# regex for parsing string in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

Just a small question. I need to parse

> xyz1/Allrun1Mbps_10000us.sca

and extract values between "_" and "us" (here for example `10000`). I am not able to create the regex properly for it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html), matlab supports lookarounds. `(?<=_).*?(?=us)` uses **lookarounds** to check the information before or after is present. `_` and `us` respectivelly. You can rename the `_` and `us` depending on your needs.

You could also use the site I mentioned to craft your own regular expressions from now on. The first result of google when you write "matlab regex" has all the answers you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this _(.*?)us. $1 gives the result.

or in more specific _(\d+?)us